# How to create same Temporary table in ELSE IF Statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am storing data into '#tempQuantity' temp table on different condition using `else if` statement like below

```
IF(@GroupKey = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ItemID,
        StoreID,
        sum(Qty) Quantity,
        sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
        sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
    into #tempQuantity
    FROM 
        dbo.F_ItemDailySalesParent

    WHERE
        ((@DateFrom is null) or (Time>=@datefrom)) and ((@DateTo is null) or (Time<=@dateTo))
    GROUP BY ItemID,StoreID
END
ELSE IF(@GroupKey = 2)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Year(Time),
        ItemID,
        StoreID,
        sum(Qty) Quantity,
        sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
        sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
    into #tempQuantity
    FROM 
        dbo.F_ItemDailySalesParent

    WHERE
        ((@DateFrom is null) or (Time>=@datefrom)) and ((@DateTo is null) or (Time<=@dateTo))
    GROUP BY Year(Time),ItemID,StoreID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Year(Time),
        DATEPART(WEEK,Time),
        ItemID,
        StoreID,
        sum(Qty) Quantity,
        sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
        sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
    into #tempQuantity
    FROM 
        dbo.F_ItemDailySalesParent

    WHERE
        ((@DateFrom is null) or (Time>=@datefrom)) and ((@DateTo is null) or (Time<=@dateTo))
    GROUP BY Year(Time),DATEPART(WEEK,Time),ItemID,StoreID
END
```

While execute this `Alter stored procedure`, it throws error **"There is already an object named '#tempQuantity' in the database."**

I understand the error. But It will not create 2 temp table at the same time. Then why it throws. Then How can I create temp table like this

**Note**

> **I couldn't drop too, before it creating table in second ELSE IF Statement**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the temp table first.

Then use `INSERT..INTO` in any `IF..ELSE` statement.

using table variable is not a good idea as it will have performance issue.

To create temp table easily, use below code in the beginning of your script

```
-- check if table exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempQuantity') IS NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempQuantity

-- simply create the temp table using 1=2 in where clause
SELECT 
    Year(Time),
    ItemID,
    StoreID,
    sum(Qty) Quantity,
    sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
    sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
into #tempQuantity
FROM 
    dbo.F_ItemDailySalesParent
where 1=2
```

Then use `INSERT..INTO` instead of `SELECT..INTO` in all your IF conditions

Answer (score 3):

1. You could declare a local table and insert data by `insert into ... select...`

   ```
   DECLARE @TempTb AS  TABLE (Id int)
   IF(@GroupId = 1)
   BEGIN

       INSERT INTO @TempTb
       SELECT 1
   END
   ELSE 
   BEGIN

       INSERT INTO @TempTb
       SELECT 1
   END
   ```
2. Or you could create #temp table and insert data

   ```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temptb') IS NOT NULL 
       BEGIN
           DROP TABLE #temptb
       END

   CREATE TABLE #temptb (Id int) 

   IF(@GroupId = 1)
   BEGIN

       INSERT INTO #temptb
       SELECT 1
   END
   ELSE 
   BEGIN

       INSERT INTO #temptb
       SELECT 1
   END
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You should try

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempQuantity') IS NULL
    SELECT * INTO #tempQuantity...
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO  #tempQuantity
```

If you don't want data from temp table you can delete existing data from temp table.

Comment: please read my question properly. I am inserting record in `if else statement`, It throws compile time error **There is already object in database**. If else statement execute record only one time, not multiple time

Comment: I am not sure how sql allowed you to create SP in first place.             
USE Northwind;
go
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO #TempOrders from Orders;
   
   SELECT * INTO #TempOrders from Orders;
END     I Tried above script, SQL not allowing me to create SP.